# Can I match a cell in column A to another column and return the first non blank cell after column a from the result line?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking for a formula to match the information from a cell in column A to a cell in column D and then return the first non blank cell information in columns C and D from the same line as the result in column D. I have managed to use the Match function and return the first non blank formula seperatley but cannot see a way to merge the two.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous.  You have a specific cell in column A?  You want to find its match in column D?  From the matching row, you want to return either C or D, but D will match the original cell.  So basically, you want the value in the original A cell unless there's a value in the C cell, in which case you want that instead?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that I can do this by using two columns for formula and getting the result in column A.
This assumes that the information I am looking up in Column C is held in Column E and the possible alternative is in column F.
Column A =IF(COUNTA(B1:C1),INDEX(B1:C1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B1:C1<>"",0),0)),"")
returns the first non blank cell from column B and C in the same line.
Column B =VLOOKUP(C1,$E$1:$F$10054,2,FALSE) returns the cell after the match from column E in the same line. 
Thanks to fixer1234 for the comment which made me realise I was over complicating the question.